# Django and MySql - Encoding difficulties

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem with a Django application that handles data imported from Google (via the gdata api). Basically, every text imported from Google is displaying with encoding problems on my page (e.g: 'Ceará State' is displaying as 'CearÃ¡ State').

The enconding on the mysql database is set to uft-8 and all texts are displaying correctly on my queries, but thing started to get a little weird after I did some experimenting with the Django shell:

I've altered one of these texts by hand and now it shows on the page without encoding problems, but the text echoed by the shell is still similar to the ones with encoding problems:

```
>>> v1
<Video: São Paulo is awesome!>
>>> v1.title
u'S\xe3o Paulo is awesome!'
>>> v2
<Video: CearÃ¡ State>
>>> v2.title
u'Cear\xc3\xa1 State'
```

And if I try to print the text:

```
print v1.title
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe3' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any idea on what's happening and how can I fix it? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I wrote a very dumb function to handle my problem while there's no better solution:

```
def normalize(s):
    return s.encode('utf-8').replace('Ã¡', 'á').replace('Ã³', 'ó').replace('Ã§', 'ç').replace('Ã£', 'ã').replace('Ã', 'í')

EDIT 2:
```

The problem was caused by Apache which wasn't setup to use UFT-8.

Comment: I think your shell doesn't support these encoding, have you displayed this data on templates?

Comment: Ahsan - Yes I did. The title that I have altered by hand to fix the accentuation displays correctly and the others are messed-up with weird characters replacing the accents.

Comment: @Ahsan - Note that the unicode representation of v1 on the shell was correct: 
<Video: São Paulo is awesome!> and the unicode representation of v2 was messes up: <Video: CearÃ¡ State>

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you properly you are getting error while printing the title in shell so try this as

```
print v1.title.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: My error isn't only in the shell. The text is also being displayed wrong on my templates. I've tried this function but it messed up my string even more.

Comment: I'm working on a very dumb function to handle my problem: def normalize(s):
    return s.encode('utf-8').replace('Ã¡', 'á').replace('Ã³', 'ó').replace('Ã§', 'ç').replace('Ã£', 'ã').replace('Ã', 'í')

Comment: What if google api returns other than these characters, this will not work for those one's. One might be solution if you ignore these non-ascii characters like, 'Ã¡' this will be 'A' etc.

Comment: The problem was that Apache wasn't set to uft-8 and this messed the integration with Google. After setting apache to use utf-8 the new data fetched from Google displayed correctly and I used my dumb function to fix the previously imported data.